# Geometric Series Modulus operation

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I am giving a series in the form of

```
1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4+r^5
```

I have to find modulus of a sum of series i.e i have to find this value

```
[(r^n-1)/(r-1)]%M
```

I can easily calculate the value of `(r^n-1)%M` , But the problem is how to calculate the denominator term ?
Since Inverse modulo can not be exist if both `(r-1) and M` are not co prime.

Please help how to get this value any approximation or algorithm ?

Since summation is very large, I can't calculate the value directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're proposing to compute `r^n` with the fast exponentiation recurrence

```
E(r, 0) = 1
E(r, n) = E(r*r, n/2)         if n is even
          r * E(r*r, (n-1)/2) if n is odd.
```

We can construct a similar direct recurrence for `1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^n`.

```
F(r, 0) = 1
F(r, n) = (1 + r) * F(r*r, (n-1)/2)       if n is odd
          1 + (r + r*r) * F(r*r, (n-2)/2) if n is even.
```

All calculations should be done mod `M`, of course.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do you come to that recursion ?