# Optimisation in the code for Sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I was having a look at practice problems in Codechef where I found this one. I am new at Python. I have written the code below using Python3. I am continuously getting '*Exceeding Timelimit*' Error. Looking up for some optimisation for the code.

The problem statement is as follows:

Given n and m, calculate 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + n^n modulo m.

Input:
The first line contains 1 ≤ t ≤ 10, the number of test cases. Then the test case definitions follow. Each test case is of the form: 1 ≤ n 1018, 1 ≤ m ≤ 200000

Example

```
Input:
6
1 100000
2 100000
3 100000
4 100000
5 100000
6 100000

Output:
1
5
32
288
3413
50069
```

And here is my code:

```
t = int(input())
for j in range (1,t+1):
    ans = 0
    n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    for i in range (1,n+1):
        ans = (ans + pow(i,i))%m
    print (ans)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Never understood why code review isn't a migration option

Comment: You can´t iterate n, 10^18 would take months if not years

Comment: @bphi In that case, have a look at [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1014587).

Comment: Shubham, have you tried running the code locally? Does it work as intended (disregarding speed for the moment)?

Comment: There's no way that this can be brute forced, not at this input range and at the run-time limit imposed. You will have to use a mathematical approach.

Comment: @Mast the code is running perfectly locally

Comment: @DeepSpace any mathematical approach in your mind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in O(m log n):

```
def geometric(n,b,m):
    T=1
    e=b%m
    total = 0
    while n>0:
        if n&1==1:
            total = (e*total + T)%m
        T = ((e+1)*T)%m
        e = (e*e)%m
        n = n//2
    return total

def efficient_solve(n, m):
    ans = 0
    for x in range(1, min(n, m) + 1):
        k = pow(x, m, m)
        s = pow(x, x, m)

        times = (n // m) + (x <= n % m)

        ans += s * geometric(times, k, m)
        ans = ans % m
    return ans
```

geometric calculates the geometric series modulo m, taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033401/3308055

**Explanation**

N is too large, we need a way to calculate multiple sums results in a single operation.

Note that `x ^ x % m = (mk + i) ^ (mk + i) % m` with i < m.

`(mk + i) ^ (mk + i) % m = (mk + i) * (mk + i) * (mk + i) * ... * (mk + i)` (mk + i) times

If we started distributing that, almost all results would have at least 1 mk as factor, and `mk * whatever % m` will be 0.

The only result without an mk factor will be `i * i * i * i * ... * i` (mk + i) times. That is, `i^(mk + i)`.

So if n = 5 and m = 3, instead of solving `1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 + 5^5 % 3` we can solve `1 ^ (0 + 1) + 2 ^ (0 + 2) + 0 ^ (3 + 0) + 1 ^ (3 + 1) + 2 ^ (3 + 2) % m`.

This is good, but we still need to do O(n) operations. Let´s try to group some of these sums. We will group based on `i % m`, we have 3 groups:

- `1 ^ (0 + 1) + 1 ^ (3 + 1)`
- `2 ^ (0 + 2) + 2 ^ (3 + 2)`
- `0 ^ (3 + 0)`

How can we calculate the result of each group efficiently?
Note that for each group, we have the same base, and the exponent increases by m for each sum. If we know the result of the first sum (`1 ^ (0 + 1)`), how does the next sum (`1 ^ (3 + 1)`) change regarding %m ?

`1 ^ (3 + 1) % m = (1 ^ 1 % m) * (1 ^ 3 % m) % m`. If n were higher and we had `1 ^ (6 + 1)` in this group, `1 ^ (6 + 1) % m = (1 ^ 1 % m) * (1 ^ 3 % m) * (1 ^ 3 % m) % m`.  Note that for each following sum in same group, we just need to add the result of `(1 ^ 3 % m)`. More generally, we need to add `base ^ m % m`.

How many sums we have in each group? Well, we will have 1 for every n < m, and then 1 more on each group every m numbers. That is, `times = (n // m) + (x <= n % m)`.

Let´s call `x` the index of the group, which will also be the base of the exponents. We will have min(n, m) groups

Let´s call `k` the result of `x ^ m % m`. Let´s call `s` the result of `x ^ x % m`.

The result of solving all the sums for this group will be:

```
s + s * k + s * k^2 + s * k^3 ... + s * k^(times - 1)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
s * (1 + k + k^2 + k^3 ... + k^(times - 1))
```

And there we have a geometric series, which we can calulate efficiently. With this, we have everything we need to calculate the answer of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a numpy solution

```
import numpy as np

n = 6
m = 100000
arange = np.arange(1, n+1)
power = np.power(arange, arange)
result = np.cumsum(power) % m
```