# Efficient calculation of all one polynomial modulus

Tags: python, modulo

The all one polynomial modulus is

`sum(x**i for i in range(n)) % m`

In my case `1 < x < m`, `0 < n < m` and *all* are integer. The sum can be simplified to `(x**n - 1) / (x - 1)`. Due to numerical issues integer division needs to be used for larger `n`. So

`(x**n - 1) // (x - 1) % m`

is equivalent. Problem is, the power can become quite huge, although Python handles this nicely it gets slow. Python’s 3 argument `pow(x,n,m)`-function can efficiently calculate powers and modulus in one step, but it’s unclear how to make use of it here. The key is probably a transformation using modulus arithmetics.

Comment: `(x**(n+1) - 1) // (x - 1)` is not the equivalent (not the same) to `sum(x**i for i in range(n))`

Comment: To add to the previous comment: `range(n)` includes integers up to n-1, so it would be `(x**n -1)//(x-1)`. For the rest: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522825/calculating-sum-of-geometric-series-mod-m

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Are you referring to the selected answer by Jim Lewis or the higher rated answer by braindoper?